# program crashes when deleting IDirect3DTexture9 texture in DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx-9

I have a clone functions in my C++ directX 9 app that copies all data of a object(such as vertices and textures) to a new object rather than having a pointer pointing to that 1 object I've created if I wanted to create multiple objects of the same type. Everything seems fine when I run it, but as soon as I quit the program, it crashes and I found out it's something to do with the textures (it's not deleting correctly.).

It seems like I'm not copying the IDirect3DTexture9 texture correctly. Here's the clone function I've got:

```
OBJMesh* OBJMesh::Clone()
{
    OBJMesh* newOBJMesh = new OBJMesh();

    newOBJMesh->vertexCount = vertexCount;
    newOBJMesh->indicesCount = indicesCount;
    memcpy(&newOBJMesh->texture, &texture, sizeof(IDirect3DTexture9));
    newOBJMesh->normalMapTexture = normalMapTexture;
    newOBJMesh->vertices = new VERTEX[vertexCount];
    memcpy(newOBJMesh->vertices, vertices, vertexCount * sizeof(VERTEX));

    DirectX::device->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(VERTEX) * newOBJMesh->GetVertexCount(), 0, VERTEXFORMAT, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &newOBJMesh->vertexBuffer, NULL);
    VOID* vertexLocking;
    newOBJMesh->vertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&vertexLocking, 0);
    memcpy(vertexLocking, newOBJMesh->vertices, newOBJMesh->vertexCount * sizeof(VERTEX));
    newOBJMesh->vertexBuffer->Unlock();

    return newOBJMesh;
}
```

I've used `memcpy(&newOBJMesh->texture, &texture, sizeof(IDirect3DTexture9));` for the texture, is this the right way of copying it? Or what exactly is wrong with it??

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to create a deep copy of a texture instead of reusing the same texture for different objects, i.e. storing a pointer to it?

Answer (score 1):

First off you should probably rethink your design as you should prefer storing pointers to objects which have already been created instead of deep copying the objects around.

Also in C++ the functionality you're looking for is typically implemented through a copy constructor which normally looks like this:

```
OBJMesh (const OBJMesh& other);
```

You could then still implement a clone function like this:

```
OBJMesh* OBJMesh::Clone() { return new OBJMesh(*this); }
```

However it's not necessary and it's more likely to lead to memory leaks as the caller becomes responsible for deleting the object, despite the fact he didn't call `new`.

Now the reason your function doesn't work is that you are copying an instance of a class interface `IDirect3DTexture9` instead of the actual texture resource. The results in this case are most likely undefined, but what you probably end up with are two objects with pointers to the same resource, which gets deleted twice upon destruction of your objects and another texture resource which you now have no handle to.

As for the solution, it depends on the problem you're trying to solve, but you probably want to have a look at [instancing](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter03.html).